# change powershell command color

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea

How do I change the command color in powershell? Currently it is yellow and when I use powershell nested in Intellij, I can't read the yellow command on white background.

[image: powershell command color]

Answer (score 12):

Regarding @LotPings answer, I solved my issue. The following command in powershell changed the command color from yellow to green:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -colors @{ Command = "Green"}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add some explanation along with your code.

Comment: Whilst this solution may work, it is always useful to add some commentary explaining your answer and which part in particular resolves the original stated problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can also set an environment variable in the terminal settings:

[IntelliJ terminal settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99R26.png)

Then edit your powershell profile and add something like this:

```
if ($env:CommandColor) {
    Set-PSReadLineOption -colors @{ Command = $env:CommandColor}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

See the cmdlets [Get-PSReadlineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/get-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-5.1) and [Set-PSReadlineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-5.1)

You may want to change:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -Tokenkind Command -BackgroundColor Black
```

Or view current settings:

```
> Get-PSReadlineOption

EditMode                               : Windows
ContinuationPrompt                     : >>
ContinuationPromptForegroundColor      : DarkYellow
ContinuationPromptBackgroundColor      : DarkMagenta
ExtraPromptLineCount                   : 0
AddToHistoryHandler                    :
CommandValidationHandler               :
CommandsToValidateScriptBlockArguments : {ForEach-Object, %, Invoke-Command, icm...}
HistoryNoDuplicates                    : False
MaximumHistoryCount                    : 4096
MaximumKillRingCount                   : 10
HistorySearchCursorMovesToEnd          : False
ShowToolTips                           : False
DingTone                               : 1221
CompletionQueryItems                   : 100
WordDelimiters                         : ;:,.[]{}()/\|^&*-=+'"–—―
DingDuration                           : 50
BellStyle                              : Audible
HistorySearchCaseSensitive             : False
ViModeIndicator                        : None
HistorySavePath                        : C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\Cons
                                         oleHost_history.txt
HistorySaveStyle                       : SaveIncrementally
DefaultTokenForegroundColor            : DarkYellow
CommentForegroundColor                 : DarkGreen
KeywordForegroundColor                 : Green
StringForegroundColor                  : DarkCyan
OperatorForegroundColor                : DarkGray
VariableForegroundColor                : Green
CommandForegroundColor                 : Yellow
ParameterForegroundColor               : DarkGray
TypeForegroundColor                    : Gray
NumberForegroundColor                  : White
MemberForegroundColor                  : White
DefaultTokenBackgroundColor            : DarkMagenta
CommentBackgroundColor                 : DarkMagenta
KeywordBackgroundColor                 : DarkMagenta
StringBackgroundColor                  : DarkMagenta
OperatorBackgroundColor                : DarkMagenta
VariableBackgroundColor                : DarkMagenta
CommandBackgroundColor                 : DarkMagenta
ParameterBackgroundColor               : DarkMagenta
TypeBackgroundColor                    : DarkMagenta
NumberBackgroundColor                  : DarkMagenta
MemberBackgroundColor                  : DarkMagenta
EmphasisForegroundColor                : Cyan
EmphasisBackgroundColor                : DarkMagenta
ErrorForegroundColor                   : Red
ErrorBackgroundColor                   : DarkMagenta
```

Comment: i could not use the `-Tokenkind` option.

Answer (score 0):

Visite this [Link](https://beebom.com/how-change-powershell-color-scheme-windows-10/) to know how to change PowerShell command color.

Also, You can use [Ohmyz](https://ohmyz.sh/)  for customizing your PowerShell also they have some awesome **plugins** and **themes**

Comment: And which entry I have to change? I tried $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor, but the ugly yellow still remains

Comment: I'm on Linux right now so I cannot help you about that appropriate $host name but you may try Ohmyz and also it have greate thems